# What's this game depicting an old viking in the middle of a big character sheet with futhark script?

Tags: identify-this-game

On a French-language boardgame site, someone is looking to identify this game.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did a google image search of this and after following a few leads I found it is from Runaljod: The sound of the runes.  [BGG link here](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/283208/runaljod-sound-runes)

The image in question can be found of the games [Kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/runaljod/runaljod-the-sound-of-the-runes) as the "Berserk" character.

[image]

Comment: Is this considered a «Viking» game, or would it be considered «Old Norse» ?